# conditionally check toggle switch c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm using c# on VS2012 
After installing NI Measurement Studio 2013 for Visual Studio 2012, I created a windows form and added a toggle switch to it. 
in the code I wanted to check if the toggle switch state has changed, but I am running into problem, I am sure that like may of the questions asked here, this is a simple matter for other, but I am stuck. 
I keep getting the error:
Error   1   The event 'NationalInstruments.UI.WindowsForms.Boolean.StateChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Reading other posts I saw discussions on how the .NET framework does not allow events to be directly modified outside the class that define it, but in this case I am not trying to modify it, just get its state??

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks,

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void switch1_StateChanged(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (switch1.StateChanged = true)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: == in if statements. Below answer for short 1 conditional if.

Comment: += and -= are for modifying objects. == and != are for comparisons. IE `String a = "something"; a += " else";`  `a` is `Something else`. `int b = 1; b++;` and `b += 2;` will all increment `b`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
if(switch1.StateChanged)
{
   //do something
}
```

In C# you use `==` to compare primitive values.

Comment: tried this before I asked the question. still get the same error.

Comment: Hey Duke, if you don't want this - do you want to check if the actual State of your switch is true? For that you have to use another property, like `switch1.State`. Please provide more code that helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that you need `==` in C# for comparison, eg:

```
 if (switch1.StateChanged == true)
 {
     //do something
 }
```

However, that still doesn't make sense as StateChanged is an event. I would have expected to see something like:

```
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    StateChanged += switch1_StateChanged;
 }

 private void switch1_StateChanged(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
 {
    //do something
 }
```

This registers your `StateChanged` event handler, and the code inside it will be executed when the state change event is fired.

I think you may be misunderstanding the fact that an event is one or more functions (delegates) which get executed when the event happens, as opposed to it being some sort of boolean flag (which it isn't). Hope this helps!

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your replay. My problme is that I wanted both. I understand that witch1_StateChanged is not a boolean flag. I want to use the event to trigger a loop. but I also wanted a change in the state of the toggle to stop the loop. this is why I was asking for a conditional check. The controller I am trying to use is a toggle switch that has an on off or open close states. how can I trigger a loop when it change state then stop the loop when it change state again? Thanks

Comment: @Duke - I don't know anything about the NI stuff, but check to see what fields are in `ActionEventArgs` - almost certainly that has a field which indicates the current state, then inside `switch1_StateChanged` you can use `e.WhateverThisIsCalled` within the if statement

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using it with Value 
(switch1.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
switch1.StateChanged = true
```

is an assignment (like `x = 5`). Probably you want a comparison (`x == 5` or `b == true`) where you get a true or false (that's why you can remove the == true part.

But since StateChanged seems to be an event, you assign methods to this event which will be called after StateChanged. Your private method switch1_StateChanged is probably already such a method. Thus you don't need to check for StateChanged since this method is only called when the State was changed.

Comment: I wanted to check if the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code:
private void switch1_StateChanged(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (switch1.Value)
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            led1.Value = false;
        }
    }
```